# How to define settimeout function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem with `setTimeout` function. When js create a div into body then remove it 2 seconds later. Here is my js file:

```
function copySuccess(msg) {
    // If file successfully copied
    const success = document.createElement('div');
    success.classList.add('payment__success');
    let successBody = document.createElement('div'),
        successPrimary = document.createElement('span'),
        successSecondary = document.createElement('span');
    successBody.classList.add('payment__body');
    successPrimary.classList.add('payment__body--primary');
    successSecondary.classList.add('payment__body--secondary');
    success.appendChild(successBody);
    successBody.appendChild(successPrimary);
    successBody.appendChild(successSecondary);
    document.body.appendChild(success);

    successPrimary.innerText = 'Successfully copied:';
    successSecondary.innerText = msg;

    function removeMsg() {
        document.body.removeChild(success);
    }

    let myVar = setTimeout(removeMsg, 2000);

    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Comment: *"What did i do wrong ?"* You're clearing the timeout before the function gets executed. *"Any advice ?"* Don't clear the timeout.

Comment: what means this ? Is `clearTimeout(myVar)` immediately works ?

Comment: Yes. You don't need the clear anyway, `setTimeout` runs just once.

Comment: Ahh Thank you guys :) I thought its wait 2 second then `cleatTimeout` works.